# How to unnest and order an array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, unnest

Is there a way to specify the order of unnesting a string from an arrary? I'm building a report in sql that takes a description of a baseline_intake_form for cars and takes the response the customer's response and puts it in a report. I know `unnest()` doesn't guarantee a specific order to flattening an array, but is there a way to order the second query so that when I join both together the results appear in the same order all the time?

The intake code is as follows:

```
select 
form_submit_id
, b.form_baselines
from claim_warehouse.aggregate_intake_form_baselines 
left join unnest (form_baselines) b
where form_submit_id=1234 
and key="target"
```

The returned result is: `Collision damage, repair exterior, fresh paint, potential totaled vehicle`
That is what I am expecting.
When I look at the response description of online forms I get a different variation:
Code:

```
SELECT 
form_id 
, form_submit_id 
, m.metadata.answer_description
FROM client_warehouse.client_response_forms forms
left join unnest(form_metrics) m 
where form_submit_id = 1234 and m.key = 'response'
```

Results: "repair exterior, potential totaled vehicle, Collision damage"

Expected Results:

```
     form_id |  baseline        | response 
     ----+----------------------+---------------------
     1234    |  collision damage| collision damage|
```

For space reasoning I shortened the expected results

Full join example looks like such:

```
select 
base.form_submit_id
, forms.client_login_acct_num
, b.form_baselines
, m.metadata.answer_description
from claim_warehouse.aggregate_intake_form_baselines base 
left join unnest (form_baselines) b
left join client_warehouse.client_response_forms forms
on base.form_submit_id = forms.form_submit_id
left join unnest(form_metrics) m 
order by
1, 3, 4
```

Comment: without the source data tables CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO we can not help you see [mre]

Comment: Why not use `order by form_submit_id, b.form_baselines` for the first one, `order by form_id, form_submit_id, m.metadata.answer_description` for the second one? As long as the locale/collations match between where you run these queries, the order of array elements will be aligned after unnesting.

Comment: Hey @Zegarek sorry for the confusion, I updated the code to reflect the actual join. It's being ordered, just when it gets unnested the `baseline` is unpacking in order and the `answer_description` can be out of order.